# sendKeys Not Working IE

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have three fields on a website which I am populating with joda time. In Firefox everything works just fine. In IE however the IRB expiration date field gets populated the Start Date and End Date fields are not populating. Any thoughts? This is with IE9. I have updated to the latest version of joda time and am still getting no joy. I have updated WebDriver and the IEDriver to 2.37. The time is being output correctly when I send it to console.

```
//Enter an IRB Expiration Date - This is the one which works
WebElement irbExpCP = driver.findElement(By.id("irbExpDate"));
irbExpCP.click();
LocalDate irbDate = LocalDate.now().plusYears(5);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
String irbDate2 = formatter.print(irbDate);
irbExpCP.sendKeys(irbDate2);

//Enter a Start Date
WebElement startDateCP = driver.findElement(By.id("startDate"));
startDateCP.click();
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.now();
String startDate2 = formatter.print(startDate);
startDateCP.sendKeys(startDate2);

//Enter an End Date
WebElement endDateCP = driver.findElement(By.id("endDate"));
endDateCP.click();
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.now().plusYears(10);
String endDate2 = formatter.print(endDate);
endDateCP.sendKeys(endDate2);
```

Comment: Why are you creating three identical `DateTimeFormatter` objects? Have you done any diagnostics to check whether the element is even being found? This feels like it's more of a Selenium/WebDriver issue than a Joda Time issue...

Comment: I thought that might help, it didn't and have removed them. I did a `System.out.println(startDate2)` and `System.out.println(endDate2)` Joda Time seems to be doing the correct thing. I will recategorize this question. Your assumption is correct, this does appear to be more of a webDriver issue than that of joda time.

Comment: Does your test fail or goes into wait?

Comment: where, what exception you are getting ?

Comment: Are there any Javascript events associated with the input fields? Can you show us the page or at least the relevant parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution :** Try `Actions Class` with `sendKeys()` method :

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(yourElement, textToEnter).build().perform();
```

---

**Note :** In IE mostly `sendsKeys()` print half or single character randomly. By above solution we can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases that I can think of:

1.) Make sure you are able to select and **get focus on** the elements. 
    Sometimes you may need to focus on the element before entering something in it.
So try to get focus on the elements
using this method (just an example)

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("myid")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("myid")).sendKeys("text");
```

If this was the case this should work fine.

2.) Other case my be due to the IEDriver architecture. I had `core i5` and was trying on `IEDriver` for `64 bit`, which caused several problems, (like sendkeys was working very slowly around 3-4 seconds before tying next letter). So just try changing the `IEDriver` if this is the case.